# XAML tabular data view

Tags: c#, xaml, view

I am developing Windows Store app using C# and XAML. I am displaying data in a text block called `greetingOutput` in the following code.

```
try
{
    var response = navigationParameter.ToString();

    var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(QualityRecordsRootObject));
    var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(response));
    QualityRecordsRootObject qualityRecordsRootObject = (QualityRecordsRootObject)serializer.ReadObject(stream);

    greetingOutput.Text = String.Format("{0,60}{1,60}{2,60}{3,60}",
                          "Brand",
                          "Printer",
                          "Printer Location",
                          "Date Received");

    greetingOutput.Text += "\n\n";




    for (int i = 0; i < qualityRecordsRootObject.auditDTOList.Count(); i++)
    {
        greetingOutput.Text += String.Format("{0,60}{1,60}{2,60}{3,60}",
                         qualityRecordsRootObject.auditDTOList[i].brandName,
                         qualityRecordsRootObject.auditDTOList[i].printerName,
                         qualityRecordsRootObject.auditDTOList[i].printerLocationName,
                         qualityRecordsRootObject.auditDTOList[i].receivedDate);

        greetingOutput.Text += "\n";
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("exception: " + ex.Message);
    greetingOutput.Text += "    No Records Found!";

}
```

But it is not looking good; I want to have tabular data view which looks good. Is there any workaround in XAML? Also I would like to add functionality to each row so that if I click a row, It goes to a particular link.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: I want to have tabular view like this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750416.aspx but I want to know how to bind data with XAML. Also I want every row to be clickable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Listbox as follows to give the required view.

```
<ListBox Name="ResultListBox" 
         Height="500" Width="1000" Margin="0,20,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
         Visibility="Visible" SelectionChanged="ResultListBoxSelectionChanged" 
          >

                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>

                        <DataTemplate>

                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

                                <TextBlock Width="250" Text="{Binding brandName}"   />
                                <TextBlock Width="250" Text="{Binding printerName}"   />
                                <TextBlock Width="250" Text="{Binding printerLocationName}"  />
                                <TextBlock Width="250" Text="{Binding receivedDate}"  />

                </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

and for code behind C# as follows.

```
ResultListBox.ItemsSource = qualityRecordsRootObject.auditDTOList;
```

I hope this would help someone.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a DataGrid. This is the msdn for a DataGrid: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/system.windows.forms.datagrid.aspx